# Why is nothing else accessible other than Google or Youtube?

Tags: internet, internet-connection

I am not sure if this is the right place, but suddenly I am not able to access the internet except Google and YouTube through my wifi router. What might be the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: In theory, you just accessed Super User too. Might be worth pinging a website that dosen't work by DNS and IP to check whether its DNS...  in addition 8.8.8.8 is useful to ping. And work from there.

Comment: Its difficult to answer without a lot more info and diagnistics - but it may be an ISP fault related to peering.

Comment: Are you able to access ipv6-test.com or ping `2600::`?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I accessed SuperUser from another network. All of the pings to various websites from terminal returned `Time Out`